# Cookie Redirect For Multiple Categories And Subcategories Under Each Country

Tags: redirect, cookies, categories, country

Would someone show me how to set cookie redirect for multiple categories and subcategories under each country? I am looking for a drop down menu for this. Thank you.

I have multiple categories and subcategories under each country. Some of the subcategories are base on that country and some are sharing the same subcategories. For example,

Country: US, Canada

mysite.com/news/localnews  (content base on location)

mysite.com/health/medicine  (share content)

If I go to mysite.com, select "US" and click "News/Local News" it will take me to mysite.com/news/localnews/us page. If I exit then go back to mysite.com and click "News/Local News" it automatically redirect me back to mysite.com/news/localnews/us page.

The selection of "US" will not affect mysite.com/health/medicine page, meaning both US and Canada's users can visit the same page without cookie.

Comment: What CMS are you using? It's hard to provide general-case help when we don't know anything about your APIs.

Comment: I am not using any CMS yet. I am currently looking for a script for a drop down menu. Thanks.